# Windowsで.batファイルを右クリックしても"プログラムから開く"メニューがない

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

Windowsの.batファイルを`プログラムから開く`にはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
右クリックしても`プログラムから開く`メニューが見当たりません
Atom Editorなどを使って開きたいです
ただし、拡張子の関連付けを変更したくはありません。(普通に開くとcmd.exeで実行されるようにはしておきたい)
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

OS: windows10 Home 1709

Comment: bat拡張子のファイルに『プログラムから開く』メニューがどうしても必要ですか？メニューが必要なのではなく、やりたい事、実現したい事を書くと回答が付きやすいと思いますよ。

Comment: win10はhomeでしょうか？homeには`gpedit.msc`が無いので苦労しますが、[WinServ2008と同じやり方](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc732272%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)ではどうでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルでは`.bat`の開き方を尋ねていますが、質問本文は`プログラムから開く`について尋ねているようで、本当に質問したい内容にまとめることは出来ませんか？

Comment: わかりやすいように質問を修正しました。

Answer (score 3):

「送る」を使う方法があります。

エクスプローラーで `shell:sendto` を開いて、プログラムのショートカットを作成してください。.bat ファイル を右クリック→送る→作成したショートカット を選べばプログラムから開くことが出来ます。

Answer (score 2):

送るなどに入れても実現できますが、`右クリック～送る～Atom`と選択するよりも、`右クリック～Atom`とできた方がワンクッション少なくて良いかな？と思うのでレジストリをいじる方法を提案します。

---

1. レジストリを開く

`Windows + r`を押して`regedit`を入力、レジストリエディタを起動します。
`\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\`に移動します。
`*`の並びにズラッと並んでるのは拡張子です。
今回は`.bat`だけを対象にしようとしたんですが、どうにもできなかったので`*`でやります。
`*`以下に設定すると全てのファイルが対象になるので、bat以外のファイルのメニューにも増えてしまいますが...

2. atom用のキーを作る

`*`を右クリックして[新規]-[キー]を選択。新しいキーの名前を`shell`に変更。
更にその下に`atom`というキーを作る。この`atom`という名前自体は何でも良いです。

3. 右クリックメニューを作る

先程作ったキー`atom`をクリックすると、右側に`(規定)`というのがあると思います。
(規定)をダブルクリックするとダイアログが開くので、『値のデータ』というところにメニュー名を入力してやります。
今回は`Open with Atom`にします。
※本来、任意のメニュー名が設定できるんですが、この設定をしてAtomを起動すると、Atom本来の設定と被ってしまって強制的にメニュー名が変えられてしまうようです。

4. 実行ファイルを指定する

先程作ったキー`atom`の下に`command`というキーを作ってやります。
できた`command`をクリックすると、右側に`(規定)`というのがあります。
(規定)をダブルクリックするとダイアログが開くので、『値のデータ』というところに実行ファイルへのpathを入力してやります。
atomの実行ファイルが`C:\Users\hoge\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.2\atom.exe`にあるとしたら、
`"C:\Users\hoge\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.2\atom.exe" "%1"`
と指定してやります。
ちなみに、ダブルクォーテーションで囲んでやらないと、半角スペースなどを含むpathで開けないことがあるので注意。

5. 試してみる

適当なbatファイルを右クリックしてみてください。
`Atom Editor`というメニューが増えて、そのメニューを選択するとAtomが起動すると思います。
最初に言いましたが、全てのファイルでメニューが追加されてると思うので、txtやdocx、html、jsなどでも同様のメニューで開けることを確認してみてください。

---

参考までに、Atomだけで良いのなら、Atomの設定から簡単に右クリックメニューに『Open with Atom』というメニューを追加・削除できますよ。

[File]-[Settings]でSettingsが開く。
Systemを選択で表示される
`Show in file context menus`で、全ての種類のファイルの右クリックメニューに、
`Show in foler context menus`で、フォルダの右クリックメニューに、
`Open with Atom`というメニューが追加できます。

Answer (score 0):

- 開きたいプログラムにD&Dする
- 右クリックで編集を押す

お好きな方を

Answer (score 0):

.batファイルには、コマンドプロンプトで実行されるプログラムを書きます。
なので、コマンドプロンプトで.batファイルを実行することが出来ます。

具体的には、以下のような操作をします
・コマンドプロンプトを起動して、コマンドプロンプトのウィンドウに.batファイルをドラッグ＆ドロップする。
・コマンドプロンプトで、.batファイル名を入力してリターンキーを押す。（.batファイル名の前にフォルダ名を付ける必要がある事もある。どのフォルダーに居るのかに依存）

[補足]
.batファイルがメッセージを表示するものの場合、「送る」でショートカットを作って、それをクリックする方法は良くありません。というのは、ショートカットをクリックするとコマンドプロンプトが起動されて、.batファイルが実行され、実行が終わると同時にコマンドプロンプトが終了（画面から消える）するので、メッセージを読む余裕がないからです。